# Python: Save Audio Stream from URL to WAV file in a loop

Tags: python

I am currently recording sounds via the IP Webcam app over my Android Device, streaming it locally to an URL that basically looks like this: "192.168.x.xxx:XXXX/audio.wav" and I want it to constantly save it into a .WAV file in a loop, so I can basically hear the sounds with a bit of a delay in my Python Script. First of all, is that even possible? Second of all, what would be the best and easiest answer?
Or are there any better solutions, because I could guess that my idea will be pretty CPU intensive.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: What does your code currently look like?

Comment: @aaldilai No code for that yet, I tried experiment but nothing worked out. I only have another project that I could combine with any suggestion that comes up.